# I'm having trouble connecting to my MySQL RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, rds

I created an RDS MySQL DB following the AWS steps but I can't connect to it.

I tried disabling the firewall and nothing works and I tried using allow everyone in the security profiles for the DB.
In telnet is giving a Connection timeout error and MySQL workbench gives Can't connect to MySQL server on 'DBSTRINGFORCONNECTION.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110) error.

My VPC layout is:

10.0.0.0/16

My Subnet layout is:

10.0.0.0/24

10.0.1.0/24

10.0.2.0/24

If you need any other info please let me know.

Comment: You have configured the server to allow remote connections?

Comment: Yes. That's why I don't understand why it isn't working. I followed the AWS tutorial twice and it doesn't work.

Comment: I added some info to the question in case that helps

Comment: I think I just found the problem @Ramhound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to fix this I went to Rout Tables and in Edit routs I removed the one that says "0.0.0.0/" and added a new route with the destination to 0.0.0.0/ and in the target I selected my Internet Gateway.